# How can I get a integer from indeed pages

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to make web **scraper** after having Python class.
And I have a problem in understanding about structure of web-page.
To make a list of page numberm, I need to extract interger form webpage. But, now the structure of webpage is changed.
Every number is in `<li>`. but the each of them is marked as different way.
For example, Interger 1 is in `<b>` tag and the others are in `<a>` tag
In this case, which way is the best way to extract those intergers with one line code?

I tried with:

```py
pagination = indeed_soup.find("ul", {"class": "pagination-list"})["aria-label"]
pagination = indeed_soup.find("ul", {"class": "pagination-list"}).get_text
```

But I can't get a right result.
Please, if is there any idea, help me.
Thank you

[image]

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: Sure!
https://es.indeed.com/ofertas?as_and=python&as_phr=&as_any=&as_not=&as_ttl=&as_cmp=&jt=all&st=&salary=&radius=25&l=Espa%C3%B1a&fromage=any&limit=50&sort=&psf=advsrch&from=advancedsearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get numbers from page-navigation, you can use next example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://es.indeed.com/ofertas?as_and=python&as_phr=&as_any=&as_not=&as_ttl=&as_cmp=&jt=all&st=&salary=&radius=25&l=Espa%C3%B1a&fromage=any&limit=50&sort=&psf=advsrch&from=advancedsearch"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

print(
    [
        int(t)
        for li in soup.select(".pagination-list li")
        if (t := li.get_text(strip=True))
    ]
)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 
But, I am a beginner and I can't understand some of them.
the 't' of int(t) works as a variable??

Comment: @SeowooJang `soup.select(".pagination-list li")` is CSS selector -> it selects all `<li>` tags under tag with `class="pagination-list"`. Then it iterates over selected tags and calls `.get_text()` on them to obtain the text from the tags.

Comment: Okay. now i understand. 
But I have one question. Before, I post this question. I wrote right this. 

url = "https://es.indeed.com/ofertas?as_and=python&as_phr=&as_any=&as_not=&as_ttl=&as_cmp=&jt=all&st=&salary=&radius=25&l=Espa%C3%B1a&fromage=any&limit=50&sort=&psf=advsrch&from=advancedsearch"

indeed_info = requests.get(url)
indeed_soup = BeautifulSoup(indeed_info.text, "html.parser")
pagination = indeed_soup.find("ul", {"class": "pagination-list"})
pages = pagination.find_all("li").get_text()
print(pages)

But i didn't work, Is there any problem in my code??

Comment: @SeowooJang Yes, `.find_all()` returns a `ResultSet`, it doesn't have `.get_text()` method. You need to iterate over each element of this `ResultSet` and call `.get_text()` individually.

Comment: Okay. So It is why Python told me 'AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get_text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?'
Thanks you very much. it was very helpful!